# Trying to write data in a Plist - almost there

Tags: ios, nsarray, plist

So I am trying to puzzle this together - I have made a small single view application to learn from:-)

What I am trying to achieve as you can see by the accommodated code and images is that I have one textField and a submit to UITable Button - The First UIView I have embedded in a navigation view, so that the the UITableView can show it's results. Now I am getting 2 errors and I know I am forgetting something, but I cannot figure out how to write declare them.

Code of AddingViewController.h

```
@interface AddingViewController : UIViewController {

Dfetch *dao;
IBOutlet UITextField *addToPlistTxt;
IBOutlet UITableView *table;

NSArray *testList;

}

 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *addToPlistTxt;
 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;

 @property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *testList;

 -(IBAction)makeKeyBoardGoAway;
 -(IBAction)submitToPlistAction;

 @end
```

Code for AddingViewController.m:

```
@implementation AddingViewController
@synthesize addToPlistTxt;
@synthesize table;
@synthesize testList;


   //Not very elegant way to dismiss keyboard, but it will do for the excersize
   -(IBAction)makeKeyBoardGoAway{    
    [addToPlistTxt resignFirstResponder];
    }

   -(IBAction)submitToPlistAction{

    NSString     *path     = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSString     *addLine  =   self.addToPlistTxt.text;
    NSArray      *values   = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:addLine, nil];
    NSArray      *keys     = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NAME_KEY, nil];
    NSDictionary *dict     = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
    [self.testList addObject:dict];
    [self.testList writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

   @end
```

Now I am just trying to learn this, hence I pasted the whole files so that I can see where I have gone wrong.

The errors are:

```
NSArray      *keys     = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NAME_KEY, nil];
```

and

```
[self.testList addObject:dict];
```

Once I got these 2 sorted, should that be set for me to add data to my pList?

I have added a screenshot below so you do not need to visualize the UI:-)

[image]

I hope all this makes sense - Thanks for any advice:-)

Cheers Jeff

Comment: your massive question still needs a bit more detail: what kind of errors are you getting?  what is "`NAME-KEY`" defined as?

Comment: Yeah I know it is massive sorry, I just tried to add as much detail as I could :-)  Defining Name_Key is the one thing I am stuck on - I am not sure where and how to do that. I have called it NAME_KEY because it in the Plist is is called name under key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAME_KEY should be some string, defined *above* where it's referred (either in the `.h` interface file or the `.m` implementation file).

E.G.:

```
#define NAME_KEY @"jwk82"
```

As for the `dict` not being added, I'm wondering if your `addToPlistTxt` UITextField is nil and that's what's causing the error (or crash).

Set a breakpoint before creating the NSDictionary object and find out.

Comment: Ok, one error is gone by, like you said, defining the NAME_KEY - but the other error stays and setting the breakpoint does not help - Its an error so it is not compiling to run on the device/simulator.

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'addObject:'

Comment: It seems I need to declare the selector addObject, which I am trying to figure out now.

Comment: Oh, duh... change the declaration for `testList` to `NSMutableArray`.  You can not add objects to a `NSArray` after creating it (it's an immutable object).

Comment: figured it out - had to change the @property settings - thanks for the input:-)